# Read json value using json path using C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json string:

```
{{
  "Data": "{\"userName\":\"Iron Man\",\"password\":\"MyPass123\"}",
  "Verb": "post",
  "Url": "/Account/v1/User"
}}
```

I need to read value for `userName` using jsonpath.
I am able to read value for Data but not for `userName`.

Try1:
`$.Data.userName`

Try2:
`Data.userName`

Try3:
`$..userName`

But no luck.

[image]

Comment: Is that really how your data looks?

Comment: If that really is how your data looks then the 'Data' property is a string, not an object

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ says that your json is invalid

Comment: you have a json-string _nested_ in your json-tring. the proper way to solve this would be to fix the code *generating* your json-string. the quick way would be to deserialise that nested string. plus: what Pavel said.

Comment: Added screen shot for reference of json

Answer (score 1):

The `Data` property within your JSON contains another serialized JSON string.  So in order to access to `userName` you will need to parse twice, once for the outer JSON and once for the `Data` JSON.  You will not be able to use a single JsonPath expression to get to `userName` from the outer JSON.

```
var outerJObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var dataJson = (string)outerJObject["Data"];
var dataJObject = JObject.Parse(dataJson);
var userName = (string)dataJObject["userName"];
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PF5wFJ